# Better to commit inside or outside a loop?

Tags: database

Maybe there's no simple answer to this question, but I ask in case someone has, if not a simple answer, at least an insight.

I've had a number of occasions where I create a loop that goes through many records in a database table performing some update, and where I could legitimately do one big commit at the end, or commit each record as I processed it. i.e. committing one at a time would not create any data integrity issues.

Is there a clear case for which is better?

What brings it to mind is that I had one such program that I recently switched from a single big commit to a bunch of little commits because it was a fairly long running program -- about 80 minutes -- and it failed half way through on bad data. I fixed the problem and re-ran, but then it had to start over again from the beginning when I could have had it just process the previously unprocessed records.

I noticed when I made this change that the run time was about the same either way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that the ability to rollback the entire persistence is not needed (in which case there is only one answer; commit outside), committing inside the loop keeps the transaction log smaller, but requires more roundtrips to the DB. Committing outside the loop is the exact opposite. Which is faster depends on the average operation count and amount of data to be committed overall. For a routine that persists about 10-20 records, commit outside the loop. For 1m-2m records, I'd commit in batches.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is do you need to rollback all if one fails? If yes, put the transaction outside, otherwise put it inside. Of course I almost never would write a loop to do an update anyway except to process fairly large batches of records. If you are doing row-by-row updates, there are better, more performant methods.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "never would write a loop to do an update anyway except to process fairly large batches". Umm, as opposed to what? If I only had one record to update, of course I wouldn't have a loop.

Comment: And yes, if the whole update must be considered as a single transaction that if only part of it was done would result in inconsistent data, of course the commit must be outside. I was thinking of cases where from a logical point of view, it doesn't matter.

Comment: As opposed to a set-based update. If you have 100 records to update, they can 99.9% of the time be done in one update with no loop and should be done that way. Daatbases are not optimized for row-by-row operations.

Comment: Very late follow-up: If you mean, I COULD write a single update, like "update my_table set foo=foo*2 where bar=5", sure, I wouldn't write a hundred separate update statements. When I posted this question I was thinking of cases where that's not possible, like you're updating based on data coming from another source.

Comment: When you are updating from another source, then it is possible and preferable to write set-based code.

Comment: This is getting into a subject unrelated to the original question. Seems to me if I have some input stream, such as a flat file or information coming over the Internet, I could write all that data to a table, and then do a single update using that table. But my guess would be that that would be slower, as if there were, say, 1000 records, I'd have to do 1000 inserts and then 1 big update, rather than 1000 updates. I'd suspect 1000 inserts would take longer than 1000 updates. Probably depends a lot on details of the schema and the workings of the engine.

Comment: In SQl server you can bulk insert to a staging table and do a set-based insert or you can use a table varaioable ina stored proc to pull all the data in or you can use SSIS. All of those would likely be faster for any large number of records than looping. Of course 1000 records is tiny , but you should be using set based methods anyway becasue that 1000 record insert now tends to be that million record insert in six months. And you need to stop think of looping as a viable choice.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of performance, it is generally better to do one big commit at the end (let network traffic, normally less work for the DB).

This of course depends on many factors, such as the indexing on the table, amount of data etc.

What should be driving your decision is how important *each* update is - should it be a transaction in and of itself? Does an update of many items make sense? What happens if the loop fails halfway?

Answering those questions will give you the right way to do this in your application for that process - you may arrive at different ways to handle the commit depending on the application context .