# Can't find any idea to print data from mysql using function

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've created a script in python capable of collecting data from a webpage and storing the same into `mysql`. When the data are properly inserted into `mysql`, my script can, however, print them in the console.

My question is: how can I wrap the following three lines within a seperate function and print the data from the storage?

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM webdata")
for item in mycursor.fetchall():
    print(item)
```

My full script:

```
import mysql.connector
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = "https://www.tripadvisor.com.au/Restaurants-g255068-c8-Brisbane_Brisbane_Region_Queensland.html"

def get_info(link):
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
      host="localhost",
      user="root",
      passwd = "123",
      database="mydatabase"
    )
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("DROP TABLE if exists webdata")
    mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists webdata (name VARCHAR(255), bubble VARCHAR(255), review VARCHAR(255))")

    response = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    for items in soup.find_all(class_="shortSellDetails"):
        name = items.find(class_="property_title").get_text(strip=True)
        bubble = items.find(class_="ui_bubble_rating").get("alt")
        review = items.find(class_="reviewCount").get_text(strip=True)

        mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO webdata (name,bubble,review) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)",(name,bubble,review))
        mydb.commit()

    #I wish to use the follwing three lines within another function to do the same

    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM webdata")
    for item in mycursor.fetchall():
        print(item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_info(URL)
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the intent of the question.  What is wrong with defining a wrapping function:  `def fetchem(cursor):` (newline, indent) `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM webdata")` (newline, indent) `for item in cursor.fetchall():` (newline, indent) `print(item)`

Comment: Python question:  Are `mydb` and `mycursor` destroyed at the end if `get_info`?

Comment: What you suggested is something I would like to cope with. However, the thing is I can't make it a go myself. If you provide the same as an answer in a more clear way, I might follow your instruction @wallyk.

Comment: @asmitu:  I've incorporated my comment into an answer below.

Answer (score 2):

My comment is meant to describe this changed code:

```
import mysql.connector
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# This is a new function
def do_fetch (cursor):
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM webdata")
    for item in cursor.fetchall():
        print(item)

URL = "https://www.tripadvisor.com.au/Restaurants-g255068-c8-Brisbane_Brisbane_Region_Queensland.html"

def get_info(link):
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
      host="localhost",
      user="root",
      passwd = "123",
      database="mydatabase"
    )
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("DROP TABLE if exists webdata")
    mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists webdata (name VARCHAR(255), bubble VARCHAR(255), review VARCHAR(255))")

    response = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    for items in soup.find_all(class_="shortSellDetails"):
        name = items.find(class_="property_title").get_text(strip=True)
        bubble = items.find(class_="ui_bubble_rating").get("alt")
        review = items.find(class_="reviewCount").get_text(strip=True)

        mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO webdata (name,bubble,review) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)",(name,bubble,review))
        mydb.commit()

    # This part is changed (moved to new function):
    do_fetch (mycursor)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_info(URL)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the following is how you can seperate things into different functions and print the data as required. Make sure to commit outside of the for loop like how it is suggested ***[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892861/better-to-commit-inside-or-outside-a-loop)***.

```
import mysql.connector
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.tripadvisor.com.au/Restaurants-g255068-c8-Brisbane_Brisbane_Region_Queensland.html"

def connect():
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
      host="localhost",
      user="root",
      passwd = "123",
      database="mydatabase"
    )
    return mydb

def create_table(link):
    conn = connect()
    mycursor = conn.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("DROP TABLE if exists webdata")
    mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists webdata (name VARCHAR(255), bubble VARCHAR(255), review VARCHAR(255))")

    response = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    for items in soup.find_all(class_="shortSellDetails"):
        name = items.find(class_="property_title").get_text(strip=True)
        bubble = items.find(class_="ui_bubble_rating").get("alt")
        review = items.find(class_="reviewCount").get_text(strip=True)
        mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO webdata (name,bubble,review) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)",(name,bubble,review))
    conn.commit() #this is where you should commit

def fetch_data():
    conn = connect()
    mycursor = conn.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM webdata")
    for item in mycursor.fetchall():
        print(item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_table(url)
    fetch_data()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the Django model framework it allows you interact with any table as a python object.

in an existing db you can convert it to a model as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/legacy-databases/), this would simply be a matter of setting up your *db* in django settings file

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
    'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
    'USER': 'DB_USER',
    'PASSWORD': 'DB_PASSWORD',
    'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
    'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

you could then use the django ops to create a models from the tables

```
$ python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

you'll then end up with some object definition in your `models.py` file which you can then access.

You'll end up with some object (without knowing too much about your db) like this, to which you just need to add a `__str__()` handle to, so that when you print the object it's formatted correctly:

```
from django.db import models

class ShortSellDetails(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField()
    bubble = models.CharField()
    review = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "VALUES ({0},{1}, {2})".format(
             self.name,self.bubble,self.review)
```

you can then interact with this object like all [models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/) (make sure you add your model to your `INSTALLED APPS` e.g. `shortSell` and perform `./manage.py makemigrations & ./manage.py migrate`) eg:

```
from shortSell import ShortSellDetails

details = ShortSellDetails.object.all()
for detail in details:
    print(detail)
```

Or you could also just create the objects directly using the model interface

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from shortSell import ShortSellDetails

URL = "https://www.tripadvisor.com.au/Restaurants-g255068-c8-Brisbane_Brisbane_Region_Queensland.html"
response = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")

for items in soup.find_all(class_="shortSellDetails"):
        name = items.find(class_="property_title").get_text(strip=True)
        bubble = items.find(class_="ui_bubble_rating").get("alt")
        review = items.find(class_="reviewCount").get_text(strip=True)


        ShortSellDetails.objects.create(
            name=name, 
            bubble=bubble, 
            review=review)

details = ShortSellDetails.object.all()
for detail in details:
    print(detail)
```